# Redefintion of "int main()" on Multi File project. C++

Tags: c++

Just started writing a multi-file project, but when I added the header it gave me this error:

```cpp
5   5   Source Code\lib.cpp [Error] redefinition of 'int main()'
3   0   Source Code\bridge.h    In file included from Source Code\bridge.h
5   5   Source Code\liberty.cpp [Note] 'int main()' previously defined here
```

Here is the code for project file numero 1

lib.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <String>
#include "bridge.h"

int main()
{

using namespace std;
cout << "Wazzup" << endl;


}
```

Here is the code for the header file

bridge.h

```cpp
#ifndef BRIDGE_H
#define BRIDGE_H
#include "lib.cpp"
#include "variable.cpp"





#endif
```

and finally the last file...

variable.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <String>
#include "bridge.h"

int i;
```

Comment: you posted `variable.cpp` yet building with `liberty.cpp`

Comment: Don't `#include` `.cpp` files.

Comment: The way you think `#include` works?  You're wrong.  Read up on it.

Comment: The common method is to have the compiler compile each source file separately, then have the linker combine them.  Don't `#include` the `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 3):

Your *header* file would not `#include lib.cpp`.

Read your source-code exactly as the compiler sees it:  `lib.cpp` includes `bridge.h`, which *(erroneously ...)* includes `lib.cpp` again!!  So it's now re-reading the same source code that it's now reading!

(You have the same "eating its tail" problem with `variable.cpp`, too!)

In general, `.h` files should only include other `.h` files, not any executable code files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :). I had no idea I had been doing it wrong. Thanks!